# Mixing Covariance and Contravariance

Tags: c#, generics

**Goal:**

Iterate over the following collection

```
var collection = new IImportTrigger<EventArgs>[]
{
    new FileSystemImportTrigger()
    , new TimerImportTrigger()
};
```

in this way

```
foreach (var trigger in collection)
{
    trigger.Import += trigger.OnImport;
}
```

**This is what I have so far**

```
public delegate void ImportTriggerEventHandler<in T>(object sender, T args) where T : EventArgs;

public interface IImportTrigger<out T> where T : EventArgs
{
    event ImportTriggerEventHandler<T> Import;
    void OnImport<T1>(object sender, T1 args) where T1 : EventArgs;
}

public class FileSystemImportTrigger : IImportTrigger<FileSystemEventArgs>
{
    public event ImportTriggerEventHandler<FileSystemEventArgs> Import;

    public void OnImport<T>(object sender, T args) where T : EventArgs {  }
}

public class TimerImportTrigger : IImportTrigger<ElapsedEventArgs>
{
    public event ImportTriggerEventHandler<ElapsedEventArgs> Import;

    public void OnImport<T>(object sender, T args) where T : EventArgs {  }
}
```

**Expectations:**

I would like to define the IImportTrigger with only one generic parameter.

**Problem:**

If I change my Interface definition to the following (*notice the generic argument T is not covariant any more*).

```
public interface IImportTrigger<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    event ImportTriggerEventHandler<T> Import;
    void OnImport(object sender, T args);
}
```

and hence

```
public class FileSystemImportTrigger : IImportTrigger<FileSystemEventArgs>
{
    public event ImportTriggerEventHandler<FileSystemEventArgs> Import;

    public void OnImport(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args) { }
}

public class TimerImportTrigger : IImportTrigger<ElapsedEventArgs>
{

    public event ImportTriggerEventHandler<ElapsedEventArgs> Import;

    public void OnImport(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) { }
}
```

I wont be able to create a common type for my collection

```
var collection = new IImportTrigger<EventArgs>[]
{
    new FileSystemImportTrigger()
    , new TimerImportTrigger()
};
```

because the Generic parameter is not output-safe any more.

**Question:**

Is there any way to accomplish my scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By switching OnImport to be not generic at all then use a explicit interface, then make another more derived interface that is not covariant that has the generic verson of OnImport you could pull it off.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new IImportTriggerBase<EventArgs>[]
        {
            new FileSystemImportTrigger()
            , new TimerImportTrigger()
        };

        foreach (var trigger in collection)
        {
            trigger.Import += trigger.OnImport;
        }
    }
}

public delegate void ImportTriggerEventHandler<in T>(object sender, T args) where T : EventArgs;

public interface IImportTriggerBase<out T> where T : EventArgs
{
    event ImportTriggerEventHandler<T> Import;
    void OnImport(object sender, EventArgs args);
}

public interface IImportTrigger<T> : IImportTriggerBase<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    void OnImport(object sender, T args);
}

public class FileSystemImportTrigger : IImportTrigger<FileSystemEventArgs>
{
    public event ImportTriggerEventHandler<FileSystemEventArgs> Import;

    public void OnImport(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args) { }

    void IImportTriggerBase<FileSystemEventArgs>.OnImport(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        OnImport(sender, (FileSystemEventArgs)args);
    }
}

public class TimerImportTrigger : IImportTrigger<ElapsedEventArgs>
{
    public event ImportTriggerEventHandler<ElapsedEventArgs> Import;

    public void OnImport(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) { }

    void IImportTriggerBase<ElapsedEventArgs>.OnImport(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        OnImport(sender, (ElapsedEventArgs)args);
    }
}
```

However this does give you the extra cruft of the `OnImport(object sender, EventArgs args)` method which is visible on `IImportTrigger<T>`.

---

That was to solve your problem, if I where going to do this and I am assuming correctly you just want derived classes to be able to pick up on the fact that `Import` is getting fired and you actually do not need OnImport exposed I would just do

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection = new IImportTrigger<EventArgs>[]
        {
            new FileSystemImportTrigger()
            , new TimerImportTrigger()
        };
    }
}

public delegate void ImportTriggerEventHandler<in T>(object sender, T args) where T : EventArgs;

public interface IImportTrigger<out T> where T : EventArgs
{
    event ImportTriggerEventHandler<T> Import;
}

public abstract class OnImportBase<T> : IImportTrigger<T> where T: EventArgs
{

    public event ImportTriggerEventHandler<T> Import;

    protected virtual void OnImport(object sender, T args)
    {
        var tmp = Import;
        if (tmp != null)
        {
            tmp(this, args);
        }
    }
}

public class FileSystemImportTrigger : OnImportBase<FileSystemEventArgs>
{
    protected override void OnImport(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs args)
    {
        DoSomeExtraStuffBeforeImport();
        base.OnImport(sender, args);
    }

    private void DoSomeExtraStuffBeforeImport()
    {
    }
}

public class TimerImportTrigger : OnImportBase<ElapsedEventArgs>
{
    protected override void OnImport(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnImport(sender, args);
        DoSomeExtraStuffAfterImport();
    }

    private void DoSomeExtraStuffAfterImport()
    {
    }
}
```

This gets rid of the event subscription and instead handles it as a override (Which is the normal pattern in .NET events).